# Manhwa where the main character makes a pact with a woman, enabling him to transform into fighters and gain their abilities

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm searching in for a manhwa where I think the main character (MC) is searching for his mother and makes a pact with a woman, enabling him to transform into fighters and gain their abilities. He later gets a bodyguard for the female MC and saves her.

I think female MC had orange hair and she is an important person. She has many bodyguards. The ability is, if he uses a ticket from the woman, he can gain the abilities of Muhammad Ali, the boxer, for example.

Does anyone know this manhwa?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the male and female leads? Also, can you tell us a little more about the world the story was set in? Was it medieval? Modern? Futuristic? And what kind of abilities did the main character gain?

Comment: I think fmc had orange hair and she is an important person. She has many bodyguards. The ability is, if he uses a ticket from the women, he can gain the ability from muhammed ali the boxer for exsample

Comment: And thank for welcoming me, thank you for your answer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDiz5-vfUZ8 Boo Boo Jeffries!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[The Boy of Death](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/sdxx4cl/the-boy-of-death)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Lee Kyung Ho's mind was engulfed with ending his life due to bullying and the loss of his mother. He attempts to, but is saved. His determination to commit suicide somehow entices Sierra, a grim reaper who later offers him a contract. This contract blesses him with the ability to borrow the powers of the dead in their previous life in return of sacrificing years from his lifespan. For the sake of attaining what he wishes for, he eventually agrees to it.

A high school student, Lee Kyung Ho, is tired of living. He's regularly bullied at school, and misses his mother, who gave her life to save his when he was younger. He decides to jump off a bridge into a river, hoping to be reunited with his mother in the afterlife, but somehow survives.

He's subsequently approached by a winged woman with a scythe, who introduces herself as 'Sierra, the Grim Reaper.' She offers him the use of 'Underworld Tickets,' which at the cost of one year of his life per ticket, will enable him to channel the abilities of a dead person of his choice (such as Mozart or Einstein) for one hour. He says he isn't interested. She then tells him that although he wished to be reunited with his mother in the afterlife, her soul still lingers in the mortal world, unable to find him. He says nothing and walks away.

Later that day, he encounters a trio of thugs in an alley who're mistreating a helpless kitten. He tries to stand up for the kitten, but takes a beating as a result. He then accepts Sierra's offer, and channels the abilities of Muhammad Ali to knock the thugs out.

Sierra reappears afterward, and he asks her how he can find his mother. She tells him that he needs to find a person who can see spirits, and that if he meets that person, he -- as the user of Underworld Tickets -- will be able to see spirits too.

It turns out that the person he's looking for is an orange-haired girl named Han Chae Yeon, who's the daughter of a CEO and the subject of repeated kidnapping attempts by a man who's yet to be caught or identified, and has various people working for him. As such, Chae Yeon is accompanied at all times by numerous bodyguards, which she hates and complains about to her father.

Kyung Ho applies to become one of her bodyguards in an attempt to meet her, but fails to make the right impression when being interviewed by her father, causing his application to be rejected. However, as he's about to leave, Chae Yeon sees him and insists that if she must have a bodyguard, she wants it to be Kyung Ho and he alone.

Her motivation for doing this is that she was fed up with the lack of privacy that came with being under escort 24/7, and thought she could easily give Kyung Ho the slip. Despite this, he is appointed as her sole bodyguard, and goes above and beyond to protect her on multiple occasions.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, been searching so long for it. U the best thank you!

Comment: Is he also looking for his mother somehow? Or is that part of the question incorrect?

Comment: @Malady - His mother is apparently deceased, but he's trying to make contact with her spirit. I'm presently working on an update to my answer which expand on that point, and the part about the orange-haired female lead with the bodyguards.